# += no me funciona adentro de un Loop for of

Tags: javascript, loops

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Javascript de un ATM y me funciona bien, pero pensé en mejorarlo validando la cantidad de dinero solicitada contra la cantidad de dinero disponible en el ATM, para que hice una ciclo "for of"  para obtemer la suma disponible así:

```
var caja =
[
  new Billete(50, 3),
  new Billete(20, 8),
  new Billete(10, 6),
  new Billete(5, 13),
];

var totalATM;

for( var bill of caja )
{
  totalATM += bill.valor * bill.cant;
}

consele(totalATM); //NaN
```

No entiendo porque no me hace la sumatoria y la mete en totalATM.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El operador `+=` suma un valor **al contenido actual**.

Sin embargo, tu haces

```
var totalATM;
```

Es decir, **no inicializas** la variable, por lo que su contenido **NO ES UN NÚMERO**, y **no le puedes sumar nada**.

Inicializa la variable con `0`:

```
var totalATM = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es simplemente que no inicializas la variable `totalATM`, no puedes realizar la sumatoria a la variable no inicializada, por esa razón obtienes `NAN` (Not-A-Number (No es un número)).

---

como ejemplo, si inicializas `totalATM`:

```js
var totalATM = 0;
var billvalor = 2
var billcant = 3


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   totalATM += billvalor * billcant;
 }


console.log(totalATM);
```

Si no inicializas `totalATM`, obtienes `NAN`

```js
var totalATM;
var billvalor = 2
var billcant = 3


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   totalATM += billvalor * billcant;
 }


console.log(totalATM); //NaN
```